# error: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined on passing data from parent to child component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular6, angular2-routing

I am working on a Angular application where I pass data from parent to child component. But I am getting error:

**error:**

**

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

**

I am putting code that I have used for **parent component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-two',
  templateUrl: './two.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./two.component.css']
})
export class TwoComponent implements OnInit {

  Employee: any = [ {
    name : 'Anurag',
    gender: 'male',
    dateOfBirth: '1-3-1993',
    contactPreference: 'at night',
    phoneNumber: '9471160160',
    email: 'anurag.qsp@gmail.com',
    department: 'Software Developemnt',
    isActive: 'yes',
  }];
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('two works !');
  }

}
```

Html:

```
<div *ngFor="let employees of Employee" >
   <app-one [employee]="employees"></app-one>
 </div>
```

I a puttng code of the **child compoenent** **where I have passed the data OF parent component**

ts ->>

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-one',
  templateUrl: './one.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./one.component.css']
})
export class OneComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() employee: any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
     console.log(this.employee);
  }
}
```

html ->>

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">{{employee.name}}</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="col-xs-10">

      <div class="row vertical-align">

        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <img class="imageClass" [src]="employee.photoPath" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              Gender
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              : {{employee.gender}}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              Date of Birth
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              : {{employee.dateOfBirth | date}}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              Contact Preference
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              : {{employee.contactPreference}}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              Phone
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              : {{employee.phoneNumber}}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              Email
            </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning to `employees` when you have `employee`(without **s** at the end) in `OneComponent` as an `@Input` property.

This:

```
<app-one [employees]="employees"></app-one>
```

Should be:

```
<app-one [employee]="employees"></app-one>
```